# No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider 'NuGet'

Tags: powershell, nuget

when I run this Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force it through an error. Error is

Install-PackageProvider: No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider 'NuGet'. The package provider requires 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the tags.

I try this solution but not working

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N8LY.png)

Comment: Can you run `Install-PackageProvier` in a Windows PowerShell instance? If you can't, and says, "*the module could not be loaded*", it may just be your **ExecutionPolicy** settings. So, run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy "RemoteSigned"` or whichever policy is best suited for your needs.

Comment: still get the same error

Answer (score 4):

I faced this error even when the server I was trying on was connected to the Internet. It was Windows 2016 Server and I was installing Docker Enterprise Edition.
I found a document published [here](https://docker-docs.netlify.app/install/windows/docker-ee/) seems outdated. There seems no document on docker hub on how to install EE. I also have read somewhere that

> Enterprise has been acquired by Mirantis in November 2019, and
> downloads have been removed from Docker Hub around December 2020

However I still went ahead along with those steps with some changes and managed to install and run docker EE service (not Docker Desktop) on the Windows 2016 server. In short I used "Powser Shell ISE" in admin mode, instead of "Power Shell" I also changed command parameters.

Here are detailed steps:

1. Open your Powershell ISE in Run as administrator mode. Run the command:

   ```
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
   ```
2. Now install the NuGet package using the below command.

   ```
    Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet
   ```
3. Now install the DockerMsftProvider module in PowerShell. Use the below command to do so.

   ```
    Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider
   ```
4. Then run this:

   ```
    Install-package -name docker -providername DockerMsftProvider -Verbose -Force
   ```
5. Then check if restart needed:

   ```
    (Install-WindowsFeature Containers).RestartNeeded
   ```
6. If ‘Yes’ restart server using this:

   ```
    Restart-Computer
   ```

It will install docker binaries in C:\Program Files\docker

After this you might need to start docker service manually in Windows services (services.msc) or you can use `start-service docker` command in Power Shell.

Then Test your Docker EE installation by running the `hello-world` container:

```
    docker container run hello-world:nanoserver
```

You might get this error:

> no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.16299 in the manifest list
> entries error on pulling hello-world image

It was because the sample container was not supporting our server’s AMD processor. Then you can try running this container:

```
    hello-world:nanoserver-sac2016
```

Here is sample successful output:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker run hello-world:nanoserver-sac2016
docker : Unable to find image 'hello-world:nanoserver-sac2016' locally
At line:1 char:1
+ docker run hello-world:nanoserver-sac2016
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Unable to find ...ac2016' locally:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
nanoserver-sac2016: 
Pulling from library/hello-world
bce2fbc256ea: 
Pulling fs layer
6f2071dcd729: 
Pulling fs layer
909cdbafc9e1: 
Pulling fs layer
a43e426cc5c9: 
Pulling fs layer
a43e426cc5c9: 
Waiting
909cdbafc9e1: 
Verifying Checksum
909cdbafc9e1: 
Download complete
a43e426cc5c9: 
Verifying Checksum
a43e426cc5c9: 
Download complete
bce2fbc256ea: 
Verifying Checksum
bce2fbc256ea: 
Download complete
6f2071dcd729: 
Verifying Checksum
6f2071dcd729: 
Download complete
bce2fbc256ea: 
Pull complete
6f2071dcd729: 
Pull complete
909cdbafc9e1: 
Pull complete
a43e426cc5c9: 
Pull complete
Digest: sha256:878fd913010d26613319ec7cc83b400cb92113c314da324681d9fecfb5082edc
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:nanoserver-sac2016

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (windows-amd64, nanoserver-sac2016)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run a Windows Server container with:
 PS C:\> docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore powershell

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
```

Comment: Also helped me getting the sqlserver module installed, thanks.